# I can't sign in: "An exception representing an authentication failure"

Tags: ubuntu-one, windows

I get this message "An exception representing an authentication failure" when trying to sign in on Ubuntu One for Windows for the first time.

I can sign in on the web but not in the software. I have tried to exclude it from AV and run it as Administrator and all. Still not getting any results.

What to do?

Answer (score 1):

There was an issue in the server more or less the time you ask your question. If you try again it should be ok.